# What is a securities license?

Tags: stocks, trading, broker

I need to fill in a form. It says on it: "This form asks that you list any and all securities licenses you currently hold and/or previously held."

What is a "securities license"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't know what one is, you don't have any.  It's the Series X (Series 6, Series 7, etc) securities licenses.  These licenses are required to sell specific types of securities.  They typically require some level of specific education before you can take the exam and require continued education to maintain your license.  Additionally many require you to be sponsored or affiliated with a FINRA registered financial institution like a bank or insurance company.

Here's a link to the applicable FINRA website:

http://www.finra.org/industry/qualification-exams

Comment: +1 for "If you don't know what one is, you don't have any.". Beautiful.

Comment: That was almost mean, but a very valid point, quid. +1 from me.